# How to execute a bash-skript from c without STDIN and STDOUT

Tags: linux, gcc, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm in the proccess of writing a deamon, which runs a shell-skript or any other executable upon a buzzer-press. Most of what I need works quite fine, but I'm facing a curious issue:

I do the call of the executable via execlp. And, when I do have STDIN and STDOUT open, this works just beautifully.

However, as this is supposed to be handled completely deamonized, thus in the background, I would like to run this without any console-interface. But, as soon as I close the standard interface identifiers, execlp does not work anymore.

I tried it with the snippet below: When it is run with a d as argument for debug, the identifiers will be kept open and it works. Otherwise, it does not. Thus, the question is: How to run an executable (by any means), without using STDIN and STDOUT.

Some remarks:

- The call to execlp does not return. Which means, that the syslog-call is never done and which is as expected.
- When leaving STDERR open, nothing comes up.
- The script to be called returns with an error-code (consciously for debugging reasons).
- When executing with file-handlers open, I do see the toggling of the pins and the wait-call returns the error-code of the sript.
- When executing without the file-handlers, the wait call returns the exit-status *success*.

Note, that the c call to execlp does not return. Thus, inside this little programm, it looks like success.

Here is the c-code:

```
/** Global Includes: ****************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


/** Main-Function: ******************************************************************/

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    /** Variables:                                                                  */
    pid_t     pid, sid;
    
    /** Set up the demon: ***********************************************************/
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        return -2;
    }

    /** If we got a good PID, then we can exit the parent process:                  */
    if (pid > 0) {
        printf("Sturting Deamon as PID %i.\n", pid);
        int iStatus;
        pid_t pid;
        pid = waitpid(-1, &iStatus, 0);
        if ((pid == 0) || (pid == -1)) {
            printf("Client exited unknown!\n");
        }else{
            if (WEXITSTATUS(iStatus) == 0) {
                printf("Client %i exited success!\n", pid);
            }else{
                printf("Client %i exited with error!\n", pid);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    
    /** Close out the standard file descriptors:                                    */
    if ((argv[1][0]) != 'd') {        
        close(STDIN_FILENO);
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        //close(STDERR_FILENO);
    }
    
    /** Open syslog:                                                                */
    openlog( "BuzzerD", LOG_PID | LOG_CONS | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL0 );
    
    /** Try to run:                                                                 */
    execlp("bash", "bash", "/home/pi/TexPrint", "/home/pi/SoLieb.tex", NULL);
    
    syslog(LOG_ERR | LOG_DAEMON, "FAILURE running execlp!");
    _exit(1);
}
```

Here is the sript to be called:

```
#SOURCE=$1
#TARGET=${SOURCE/tex/pdf}
#echo Compiling $SOURCE to $TARGET and print!
#echo pdflatex $SOURCE
#echo Trying to print $TARGET ...
#echo lp -d Brother_MFC_J5930DW $TARGET
#echo .

/home/pi/BuzzerD/buzzerd -l off
sleep 3
/home/pi/BuzzerD/buzzerd -l alive

exit 1
```

Comment: `execlp does not work anymore` How do you know that? What does the call return? What is the value of errno? `LOG_ERR + LOG_DAEMON` no, that's invalid. You should do `LOG_MAKEPRI(LOG_DEAMON, LOG_ERR)` (or `LOG_ERR | LOG_DEAMON`, but not `+`). Note you can test from terminal with closed stdin and stderr with `./program >&- 2>&- 0<&-`

Comment: Hi Kamil,

thanks for the hint on the log-entries. That was a slip of pen.

Regarding the execution: In the skript to be called, I'm switching ON and OFF ports of the raspberry. And this switching (which does not do anything with the console) does not happen.

The syslog call after the execlp is never executed, which is correct.

Comment: Ok. Could be you do not have permissions to switch. Or you have some `echo` in the script, which makes the script fail under `set -euo pipefail`. Please post the script. Is the script located at `/home/pi/TexPrint`? Try running the script with closed stdout - but with redirected `stderr` to some file or other location and see if something comes up.